# Protractor - pass parameters from console to conf.js

Tags: testing, npm, parameters, protractor

I have config.js like below:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],

  params: {
    browser: 'chrome' 
},

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': (params.browser || 'chrome'),
  },
 ...
}
```

Now I would like to pass 'browser' parameter from console to run it on IE instead of Chrome by default:

```
protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js --params.browser='internet explorer'
```

or

```
protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js -- --params.browser='internet explorer'
```

I've tried many configuration but everytime I get:

```
[14:17:00] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[14:17:00] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file e2e/protractor.conf.js
[14:17:00] E/configParser - ReferenceError: params is not defined
```

Can anyone help how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

not enough reputation for clarification :)

Are you sure that you call properly this part *params.browser* ? I mean *params*.
To my mind *params* is not defined. You work with object, so try this one: this.params.browser

If you define your config in *config.js*, why did you call *protractor.conf.js* ?

Finally, protractor has it's own globals. And there are some entry points where you can use it. For example you can use global protractor object "browser" in onPrepare(). To get access to the params should work something like "browser.params.browser". I am not sure that you can get access to globals within main conf file while it parsing. May be some workaround with process.argv will help you. Or rework your logic structure.

Comment: It doesn't work either with 'this' :( and to be more exact I use protractor.conf.js instead of config.js sorry for misleading you.

Comment: in that case there is only one problem - you cannot get access to protractor global object "browser" within conf file. It is better to rework your logic. For example you can add env variable (process.env.NODE_ENV) to conf file (better into another file). And launch your solution with node env variable, which will referred to your settings for it. To my mind it is good decision for your case. Do you work with _process.env_ ? If not I can create simple example

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to specify the browser name from cmd line, you can do as following:

```
protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js --browser='internet explorer'
```

And you can specify following params as same way:

```
--seleniumAddress=
--specs="['./src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts', '']"
--capabilities=<json string>
--suite=
```

Besides above `reserved` params, you can specify any params through `--params.xxx` format in cmd line and use `browser.params.xxx` format in script to use the `xxx`.

But the `browser` variable can't be used in anywhere in `conf.js`, it's only inited after the browser opened.

As [protractor website](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L461) said, you can use `browser` in `onPrepare` function and any place where is executed after protractor call `onPrepare` function.